# How to wall off a Django view based on the result of another view

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm writing a `change password` feature for a Django app of mine, allowing users to change their passwords at will. One requirement is that users must resubmit the original password before proceeding to change it.

Views responsible for `reauth of original password` and `enter new password` are mapped to two separate urls. Currently the way it's set up, one can directly get to the `enter new password` part of the functionality simply by hitting the right url. I need to make `reauth of original password` compulsory, thus the current funtionality is unacceptable.

What's the best strategy to redesign this feature such that reset password is walled off behind the reauth requirement? One thing coming to my mind is setting a flag as a session variable upon successful reauth, and allowing password reset only if the said flag is correctly set. But I'm hoping there could be a more robust way?

My current code is:

```
def reset_password(request,*args,**kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ResetPasswordForm(data=request.POST,request=request)
        if form.is_valid():
            #save new password hash
        else:
            context={'form':form}
            return render(request,'reset_password.html',context)    
    else:
        form = ResetPasswordForm()
        context={'form':form}
        return render(request,'reset_password.html',context)

def reauth(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReauthForm(data=request.POST,request=request)
        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect("reset_password")
        else:
            context={'form':form}
            return render(request, 'reauth.html', context)
    else:
        form = ReauthForm()
        context = {'form':form}
        return render(request, 'reauth.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way to do it and I would like to emphasize **I am not aware of how secure this method is**, but this can be done via sessions.

Here's an example,

```
@csrf_exempt
def render_first_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        request.session['first'] = True
        print (request.session['first'])
        return redirect('/second/')
    try:
        del request.session['first']
    except KeyError:
        pass

    return HttpResponse("<form method='POST'><input type='text' name='test'/><input type='submit'/></form>")

def render_second_page(request):

    try:
        if request.session['first'] == True:
            return HttpResponse("Welcome to Second Page")
    except KeyError:
        print ("No first")
        return redirect('/first/')
```

To start off, the second page will not render if the key 'first' does not exist in the session variable and will redirect to the first page.

On the first page when I get a POST request a token is created on the session object and subsequently, we are redirected to the second page where now the token exists and the second page is rendered.

Be sure to delete session keys at the appropriate time. I would suggest delete the token when the second page is rendered.

Comment: fair enough. Btw could you also explain why you opted to use the csrf_exempt decorator in this case?

Comment: Btw this is the approach I had in mind too. Downsides are that it's not air-tight, and there could be security issues.

Comment: Using the decorator to allow the form to Post.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/36962 I think this answer describes the risks pretty well.